# Forcing a date format in Handsontable?

Tags: javascript, handsontable

I have a Handsontable instance that uses a date column:

```
{
    'type': 'date',
    'allowEmpty': true,
    'correctFormat': true,
    'dateFormat': 'DD MMM YYYY'
}
```

When I use the date-picker widget, I get dates that are formatted as I want (e.g. `16 Aug 2017`). However, when a user pastes a value that does not match my intended format, the resulting date gets confused. So, if I were to paste the value `08/14/2017` into a cell, I would (confusingly) end up with the date `08 Jan 2014`.

How can I convert pasted (or even typed) values that are one date format into my desired format for display?

Answer (score 0):

I know handsontable got a datevalidator for things like this.
See the [doc](http://docs.handsontable.com/0.34.0/validators_dateValidator.js.html)